# PyQt get date from the user

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qt-designer

I built simple widget in Qt Designer with a button and a QDateEdit.
The user will enter the date into the QDateEdit and then when he presses the button, the date will be saved to a variable.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 21):

You can make it simply:

```
var_name = self.dateEdit.date()
```

This will get you a variable in QDate format.
If you need it in a format which would be easier to work with then you should use this:

```
temp_var = self.dateEdit.date() 
var_name = temp_var.toPyDate()
```

The first one gives you: "PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(2011, 11, 8)"

While the second returns: "2011-11-08"

Comment: Or, avoiding the temp_var: self.dateEdit.date().toPyDate()

Comment: I think that for learning purpose `explicit is better than implicit`. Although I should have included this option too. Thank you.